# Memory management issue using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, deinit

We are having some memory allocation issues.
When I am run my app and come to a certain page, the Memory count is increased by 30mb each time I come to the page.

I have added IBOutlets as Weak and declared variables as ? (i.e. Optionals), though memory is not deallocating object and `deinit()` is not getting called when I am unloading my page.

**My Code Below**
———————————

**Declaration**

```
//[Mapped Outlet With Front End]  
@IBOutlet weak var testInd: UIActivityIndicatorView!  
@IBOutlet weak var uiPendingView: UIView!  
@IBOutlet weak var uiDraftView: UIView!  
@IBOutlet weak var propertyListingTableView: UITableView!  
@IBOutlet weak var uiCompletedView: UIView!  
@IBOutlet weak var propertiesMap: MKMapView!  
@IBOutlet weak var btnSynch: UIButton!  
@IBOutlet weak var lblPendingStatus: UILabel!  
@IBOutlet weak var lblDraftStatus: UILabel!  
@IBOutlet weak var lblCompleteStatus: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var networkLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tableEmtyLabel: UILabel!  
@IBOutlet weak var lblPropertyLabel: UILabel!  
@IBOutlet weak var lblPendingLabel: UILabel!  
@IBOutlet weak var lblDraftLabel: UILabel!  
@IBOutlet weak var lblCompletedLabel: UILabel!  
@IBOutlet weak var segmentControllerSynch: UISegmentedControl!  
@IBOutlet weak var googleMapView: GMSMapView!  
@IBOutlet weak var propertyLabelView: UIView!  

//[Local variable declaration]  
var annotation: CustomPointAnnotation?  
var annotationArray : [CustomPointAnnotation]?
var properties:[Property] = [Property]()
var tempProperties:[Property] = [Property]()
var pushProperties:[Property] = [Property]()
var getProperties:[Property] = [Property]()
var draftProperties:[Property] = [Property]()
var failedProperties:[Property] = [Property]()
var property: Property?
var company: Company?
var companies: [Company]?
var allProperties: [Property]?
var xmlElementData : NSData!
var filePath:NSString?
var xmlParseString: NSString?
var xmlNSData: NSData?
var pendingFilterTick = false
var draftFilterTick = false
var compeletdFilterTick = false
var fromPopover = false
var errorStr: String?
var tokenStr: String?

var resultDict: NSDictionary?
var sortingImg   : UIImage = UIImage(named: "Sorting")!
var menuImg : UIImage = UIImage(named: "Slider")!
var leftLogo : UIImage = UIImage(named: "logo")!
var sortingBtn : UIBarButtonItem?
var menuBtn : UIBarButtonItem?
var leftBtn : UIBarButtonItem?
var emptyView: UIView!
var actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView?
var container: UIView?
var lblProcess: UILabel?
var loadingView: UIView?
let nsFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

//[Local class declaration]
var constants = Constants()
var parser = XMLParser()
var utility = Utility()
var fileMgr = FileManagement()
var xmlParser = XMLParser()
var netUtil = NetworkUtil()
var dict:Dictionary<String,String> = Dictionary<String,String>()
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
var unitCount = 0
var dateUtil = DateUtils()
var synchCompanies:[Company]?
var controllerUtil = ControllerUtil()
var errorHandling = ErrorHandling()

//[Variable declaration for the Google map]
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var didFindMyLocation = false

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    print("viewDidDisappear")

    if let superView = self.view.superview
    {
        superView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    fileMgr.deallocateReferences(xmlNSData!)
   // fileMgr: FileManagement = nil

    tempProperties = []
    pushProperties = []
    getProperties = []
    draftProperties  = []
    failedProperties = []


//        testInd = nil  
//        uiPendingView = nil  
//        uiDraftView = nil  
//        propertyListingTableView = nil  
//        uiCompletedView = nil  
//        propertiesMap = nil  
//        btnSynch = nil   
//        lblPendingStatus = nil  
//        lblDraftStatus = nil  
//        lblCompleteStatus = nil   
//        networkLabel = nil   
//        tableEmtyLabel = nil  
//        lblPropertyLabel = nil  
//        lblPendingLabel = nil  
//        lblDraftLabel = nil  
//        lblCompletedLabel = nil  
//        segmentControllerSynch = nil  
//        googleMapView = nil  
//        propertyLabelView = nil  


}
deinit{
    print("DEINIT")
   googleMapView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", context: nil)
}
```

Comment: something else is holding strong reference to your controller and not releasing it, usually "addObserver" method will not make strong reference, you can test it by temporarily not adding observer to the keypath in your didLoad.

Comment: You are referring to 'pages' when in fact you mean view controllers.

Comment: From apple doc KVO method `Neither the receiver, nor anObserver, are retained. .`

Comment: You should probably explain the way you show your "page" and how you hide it.

Comment: yes Timbo, I meant view controller not pages.

Comment: This class is massive. I would look into ways to refactor moste of the properties out into smaller classes.

Comment: I have divided into the small classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

If deinit of your view controller is not called, then someone is holding a strong reference to it. Find the culprit.

BTW. It is probably not a good idea to play around with superviews. That could create all kinds of trouble.

Comment: How would i know which strong object is holding my controller for Deinit?